# Makefile double extension pattern matching

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching

How to write the correct Makefile if I want to define generic targets of the form `a.ext1.new_ext`, `a.ext2.new_ext`, `b.ext1.new_ext`, `b.ext2.new_ext` etc. with prerequisites `a.ext1`, `a.ext2`, `b.ext1`, `b.ext2` respectively?
Kind of this but general rule:

```
a.ext1.new_ext: a.ext1
    compiler --input a.ext1 --output a.ext1.new_ext

a.ext2.new_ext: a.ext2
    compiler --input a.ext2 --output a.ext2.new_ext

b.ext1.ext: b.ext1
    compiler --input b.ext1 --output b.ext1.new_ext

b.ext2.new_ext: b.ext2
    compiler --input b.ext2 --output b.ext2.new_ext

...
```

Thanks!

P.S. I call Makefile from root directory `.`, prerequisites are in `./src/folder` and I need the output in `./build/folder`. More precisely, my Makefile:

```
SRC := $(shell find ./src -type f \( -name '*.ext1' -or -name '*.ext2' \))
OBJ := $(patsubst ./src%, ./build%, $(SRC))
OBJ := $(addsuffix .ext, $(OBJ))

# Doesn't work
%.ext: %
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    compiler --input $< --output $@
```

Comment: You should probably take a look at [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with:

```
%.new_ext: %
        compiler --input $< --output $@
```

?  If what you tried doesn't work, it's better to show us what you tried and copy/paste the not-working thing, than to ask a generic question which might lead us to give answers that don't solve your actual problem.

Comment: Good point! They are in different folders. I call Makefile from root directory `.`, dependencies are in `./src/folder` and I need the output in `./build/folder`

Comment: OK, so why not just `./build/folder/%.new_ext: ./src/folder/%` ?  Again, if you actually have a non-working case by far the best thing to do is just edit your question and copy and paste an actual, working (or not working) example along with the results you get and why they're wrong.

Comment: I've added an example. Basically I'm trying to preserve the same folder structure in `build` folder as in `src`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution is:

```
./build/%.spv : ./src/%
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(GLSL) $(GLSL_FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Thanks for you suggestions!

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my comment above.